# Android MultiAutoCompleteTextView truncate string

Tags: android, android-studio, multiautocompletetextview

I have a string MultiAutoCompleteTextview as:

```
VACUTAINER [3X10] - 30RS, VACUTAINER[4 X10] - 40RS
```

So here, I want to split the string after (-) and I also want to truncate the last two characters (RS) and get the string as 30 40 and want to sum this 30 and 40 and get the answer in another EditText.

Thank You.

Comment: is "VACUTAINER [3X10] - 30RS"  single string or "VACUTAINER [3X10] - 30RS, VACUTAINER[4 X10] - 40RS " is single string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
String[] givenString={"VACUTAINER [3X10] - 30RS","VACUTAINER[4 X10] - 40RS"};
            //or use loop
            String newStringFirst=givenString[0].substring(givenString[0].lastIndexOf("-") + 1).trim();
            String newStringSecond=givenString[1].substring(givenString[1].lastIndexOf("-") + 1).trim();
            String thirtyString=newStringFirst.substring(0,newStringFirst.length()-2);
            String fortyString=newStringSecond.substring(0,newStringSecond.length()-2);
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(thirtyString)+Integer.parseInt(fortyString));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked!!